# Python: How to filter a list of dictionaries to get all the values of one key

Tags: python, list, filter

I have a list of dictionaries in python:

```
thedata = [{'date': '2002-02', 'data': 2.0}, 
           {'date': '2002-03', 'data': 2.0017}...]
```

How do I make a list of just the 'data' values?:

```
[2.0, 2.0017...]
```

I've tried:

```
justFigures = list(filter(lambda x: x["data"], thedata))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try like so:

```
thedata = [{'date': '2002-02', 'data': 2.0}, 
           {'date': '2002-03', 'data': 2.0017}]

print([a['data'] for a in thedata])
```

Output:

```
[2.0, 2.0017]
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
In [1]: thedata = [{'date': '2002-02', 'data': 2.0},
                   {'date': '2002-03', 'data': 2.0017}]

In [2]: just_figures = [ d['data'] for d in thedata ]

In [3]: just_figures
Out[3]: [2.0, 2.0017]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
thedata = [{'date': '2002-02', 'data': 2.0}, 
           {'date': '2002-03', 'data': 2.0017}]

# back to your own way, lambda
# py 2
print map(lambda a : a["data"], thedata)

# py 3
print (list(map(lambda a : a["data"], thedata)))

>>> [2.0, 2.0017]
```